# ORC files generated by Flink can not be used in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-flink, cloudera, orc

Situation is following:

1. I write data in ORC format by Flink into HDFS:

- I implements **Vectorizer** interface for processing my data and converting it into **VectorizedRowBatch**
- I create **OrcBulkWriter**:

```
OrcBulkWriterFactory<MyData> orcBulkWriterFactory = new OrcBulkWriterFactory<>(new MyVectorizerImpl(orcSchemaString));
```

- I configure **StreamingFileSink**:

```
StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat(hdfsPath, orcBulkWriterFactory)
                 .withBucketAssigner(new BaseBucketAssigner<>())
                 .build();
```

- I deploy my job into Flink cluster and in *hdfsPath* catalog a see ORC files.

2. I create Hive table by the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE flink_orc_test(STRING a, BIGINT b) STORED AS ORC 'hdfsPath';
```

3. I try to execute query

```
SELECT * FROM flink_orc_test LIMIT 10;
```

4. I have an error

```
Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=0, operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0,
operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='a\x08\xc3U\xbb\xa7I\xce\x96\xa6\xdb\x82\xa4\xa9\xd1x', guid='\xcc:\xca\xcb\x08\xa5KI\x8a}7\x95\xc5\xcd\xd2\xf0')),
orientation=4, maxRows=100): TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0, errorMessage='java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6',
sqlState=None, infoMessages=['*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6:25:24',
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:496',
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationNextRowSet:OperationManager.java:297',
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:868',
'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25:invoke::-1', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43',
'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:498',
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78',
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63',
'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2',
'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:422',
'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1731',
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59',
'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37:fetchResults::-1',
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:507',
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:708',
'org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1717',
'org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1702',
'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56',
'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286',
'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149',
'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624',
'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:748',
'*java.io.IOException:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6:29:4',
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getNextRow:FetchOperator.java:521', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:pushRow:FetchOperator.java:428',
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask:fetch:FetchTask.java:146',
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:getResults:Driver.java:2277', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:491', '*java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:6:37:8', 'org.apache.orc.OrcFile$WriterVersion:from:OrcFile.java:145',
'org.apache.orc.impl.OrcTail:getWriterVersion:OrcTail.java:74',
'org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl:<init>:ReaderImpl.java:385',
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl:<init>:ReaderImpl.java:62',
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile:createReader:OrcFile.java:89', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat:getRecordReader:OrcInputFormat.java:1690', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator$FetchInputFormatSplit:getRecordReader:FetchOperator.java:695',
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getRecordReader:FetchOperator.java:333',
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getNextRow:FetchOperator.java:459'], statusCode=3), results=None, hasMoreRows=None)
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-cdh6.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-orc_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I think that the general problem that **flink-orc** uses **orc-core** dependency, but for correct working with hive i need a **hive-orc**. Actually, I can not replace **orc-core** with **hive-orc** because this is incompatible with **flink-orc** classes.

How can I solve it? It is preferable for me use **StreamingFileSink** for writing ORC files, not **Flink Table API with Hive**.

Hive version: **2.1.1-cdh6.1.1**

Flink Version: **1.11.2**

Comment: It seems like Flink orc version is quite old, could you try to bump it (just use a newer version in your pom.xml)?

Comment: But 1.11.2 is a latest version for this artifact. I check my code on hive 3.1.2 and ORC files can be read correctly. The problem is actual only for hive version 2.1.1.